# How do I install grunt on RHEL Server with no access to internet

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

How do I install grunt onto RHEL Server with no access to the internet ? I could get nodejs installed and working correctly through the binary downloads.

Comment: Since Grunt plugins use `npm`, and `npm` requires an Internet connection (or local proxy), I'm not sure how you're going to do that...

Comment: I was hoping there might be a way to create a RPM package with something like grunt-rpm and then basically ship only that rpm to the server and then install it with rpm package manager, but not sure how ?

Comment: Honestly not sure how you might do this... sorry!